# ¿Por qué no me funciona la inserción de una tabla de muchos a muchos en una función en laravel?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-8

Tengo un sistema de matricula, donde antes de poder matricular a un alumno, se deba iniciar periodo, luego de eso se tiene que colocar los datos del alumno, los datos del padre, madre y encargado, cada uno de ellos tiene su propia vista.

Encargado finaliza la matricula y lleva a una función donde se establece la conexión de cursos con alumnos y periodos con alumnos, todos en la misma tabla pivot llamada matricula
esto es la funcion de terminar matricula:

```
`public function terminar_matricula()
{
    $alumno_id = Cache::get('alumno_id');
    $alumno = Alumno::find($alumno_id);

    $cursoId = session()->get('curso_id');
    $alumno->cursos()->attach($cursoId);
    session()->forget('curso_id');

    $periodoActual = Periodo::where('fechaInicio', '<=', now())
                    ->where('fechaCierre', '>=', now())
                    ->first();

    if ($periodoActual) {
        $periodoId = $periodoActual->id;

        if ($periodoId) {
            $alumno->periodos()->attach($periodoId, ['periodo_id' => $periodoId]);
        }
    }

    $estado = Proceso::findOrFail($alumno_id);
    $estado->delete();

    Cache::forget('alumno_id');

    return redirect()->route('principal.create');
```

Periodo, curso y alumno estan en una tabla pivot desde el modelo, y sus migraciones, pero me sale este error cuando intento finalizar la matricula:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'periodo_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into matriculados (alumno_id, curso_id) values (2, 1))`

He intentado de todo pero aún asi no he llegado al fondo del problema, ¿Alguien podria ayudarme?

Comment: Saludos. No estoy familiarizado con esa estructura/framework que usas; el mensaje implica que al momento de realizarse el `INSERT` se esta omitiendo el valor para el campo `periodo_id` en la tabla **`matriculados`**. Busca el punto donde ello se realiza y verificar el dato se proporciona y lo que recibe.